# Dropdown system menu on top right is bigger and messed up

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, menu

A couple of days ago the dropdown menu of Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS suddenly became unusable, with big icons misplaced and a few missing ones. If I try to click on any of those, it's like the click happens in a different position -- apparently the "correct" position, like if the size and position of the icons were correct.
Also the dropdown calendar I get by tapping the system bar is not responsive.

Any idea what could be the cause and how to reset/fix this?

Here is a screenshot of the menu.

[image]

Here is my video info from `sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration`

```
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

Running `lsb_release -a` returns the following:

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: @K7AAY done - [must reach 15 chars, annoying...]

Comment: @K7AAY I have added the output. Btw I noticed that also the dropdown calendar I get when clicking on the system bar is not responsive anymore

Comment: I believe it has something to do with displays configuration. If I start the system only with my laptop screen on, everything is rendered fine. As soon as I plug the external monitor and the system bar moves there, I am back to this problem.  
Maybe deleting `~/.config/monitors.xml` could help?

Comment: It was definitely related, I solved by removing that file (removing the affected monitors is probably a better solution, but I decided to clean up the file as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After <s>an annoying amount of</s> a few trials, I found out that the monitors' configuration was responsible for this misbehavior. I solved by deleting the file in `~/.config/monitors.xml` and rebooting. This removes all your monitor configuration (resolutions & co.), which may be annoying if you use your laptop with many different monitors configurations.

Possibly, a single line in that file was causing the problem, but I couldn't easily identify it so I decided to remove all the file. I wasn't experiencing any further issues while using the system.